# Rails encrypt mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I need to do encryption / decryption via sql (mysql) in rails. The reason i need this is because i need to do this with thinking sphinx, which talks to my database in sql. What kind of tools do i need, and how do i use them (like what documentation is there, especially for use with rails, if it is not as simple as a gem) for what is out there.

Thanks for any help i get. (im on rails 3 if it helps)

Comment: What system will this run on? nix|windows... etc

Comment: Also, re-reading your question, it's not entirely clear why you need encryption, "The reason i need this is because i need to do this with thinking sphinx, which talks to my database in sql." - SQL isn't encryption. What is it you really want to achieve?

Comment: @kevin do you actually mean using an encrypted connection (e.g. SQL over SSL)?

Answer (score 0):

as others have already asked, i am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

I used encryption(loosely used) if someone who you suspect might be accessing info or databases they are not supposed to view. If it helps, you could grant privileges to users to access specific databases within mysql.

Normally if your mysql is a new install you can login to it by doing this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and then press enter without typing a password then it logs you into mysql

```
mysql>
```

Lets assume we have a database called "chicken_farm_development" and we want to grant access to the user "farmer_brown"

Then we could grant privileges to "famer_brown" to only access "chicken_farm_development" database and nothing else in mysql(so farmer_brown cannot access "joes_pizza_development" database). We do this in mysql:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON chicken_farm_development.*
    -> TO 'farmer_brown'@'localhost'
    -> IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecretpassword';
```

To check that this works:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'farmer_brown'@'localhost';
```

and it should display the grants for farmer_brown.
So how can you use this?
Not really sure how thinking sphinx is setup, but you could grant access for thinking sphinx to use a specific database, without affecting any other databases you might have, and can be extrapolated to production environments.

to login to mysql as farmer_brown, you would do this:

```
$ mysql -u farmer_brown -p chicken_farm_development
Enter password:
```

and whooohooo!, farmer brown now only has access to chicken_cms_developement database. In summary you can grant access to specific databases. Hope this helps a little as it was a bit unclear as to what you were asking.